# Why does the loop in my code stops running?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the factors of a number and input them values to an array, small numbers work fine but when i tried with big number the code crashes.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

main(){
    int num,c=1,a[c],b;
    
    cin>>num;
    
        for(int i=1; i <= num; i++) {
         if (num % i == 0)
            a[c++]=i;
            
        }
            cout<<a[6];
        
}
```

Comment: You're almost certainly accessing `a` out of bounds.

Comment: Discuss `c=1,a[c]` with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 5):

```
int num,c=1,a[c],b;
```

This is not valid, standard C++. In C++ the size of all arrays is ***constant*** and specified at ***compile time***.

Specifying the size of the array as `c`, a non-`constexpr` variable, is not valid C++. Your compiler allows it as a non-standard C++ extension. And what happens is because `c`'s value is 1 at the time the definition takes place, this is effectively the same as defining

```
int num,c=1,a[1],b;
```

Afterwards:

```
         if (num % i == 0)
            a[c++]=i;
```

Subsequently, this ends up scribbling over `a[1]`, `a[2]`, and so on. However, there is no `a[1]`, or `a[2]`. The size of the array is 1, so the only valid array index is `a[0]`.

You might be thinking that just because the size of the array is declared as `c`, then modifying `c` automatically resizes the array accordingly. Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. Once the size of an array is set, using standard C++ or non-standard C++ extension, the size of the array never changes size. `c` can be set to any value, and it makes no difference whatsoever, to the array that, at one point distant past, was declared by specifying `c` as its size.

If you'd like to use something that looks like an array but whose size can be adjusted, see your C++ textbook for an explanation and a description of how to use `std::vector`. This is what `std::vector` is for.

Comment: General addendum: C++ is not a spreadsheet. if you have a formula like `int c=a+b;`, `c` is computed immediately based on the current values of `a` and `b`. If you subsequently change the value of `a` or `b`, `c` will not be updated. If you need to recompute `c` when `a` or `b` is changed, you'll have to write code that does it.